# How to use RegEx to match records in SQL Server or BigQuery (Standard Dialect)

Tags: regex, sql-server-2008

I am trying to do some data preparation on a table, I tried on SQL Server 2008 R2 Express and BigQuery:

My table is like below:

```
create table location
(
    city varchar(50),
    country varchar(10)
)

insert into location (city) values ('Rumney, NH, US')
insert into location (city) values ('Hickory Hills, IL')
insert into location (city) values ('Patchogue, NY')
insert into location (city) values ('Wilton, NH')
insert into location (city) values ('Cedarville University, OH')
insert into location (city) values ('Shopshire, UK')
insert into location (city) values ('Dreilinden, Germany')
insert into location (city) values ('Jarjis, Tunisia')
insert into location (city) values ('Casca/RS, Brasil')
```

I want to select all records with city in USA, the regex I am using is:

```
(?!.*UK),\s(\w{2})$
```

Here is the proof:

[image]

My query in MS SQL is like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM location 
WHERE  city LIKE '(?!.*UK),\s(\w{2})$'
```

It returns nothing.

I also tried adding `%` around the pattern, and `PATINDEX`, but I'm still not getting anything.

--- Per indicated by @marc, MS SQL doesn't accept real regex.

In BigQuery:

```
select location, REGEXP_CONTAINS(location, "(?!.*UK),\s(\w{2})$")  
from `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.users` 
limit 10;
```

I see an error in the editor (same error when I change double quotes to single quote):

[image]
What am I missing here?

Thank you very much if you can help to sort it out.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't  **really** support regexes...... the support is **extremely** limited (`PATINDEX` and `LIKE` - that's about it).

Comment: Thank you marc, what about in BigQuery?

Comment: You need to escape the ```\``` in your regex expression i.e. `"(?!.*UK),\\s(\\w{2})$"`

Comment: Thank you Nick, the query is now validated, however, I got a new error message: `Cannot parse regular expression: invalid perl operator: (?!`